# ASP.NET MVC2 Checkboxes in a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm currently trying to create a view in asp.net MVC2 which includes a checkbox in each row. This will be a "mark" box, and there will be a button on the view which can then be used for multiple deletion.

I have a model which contains a list of the objects being listed, so I have some code which reads as:-

```
<% foreach (CancelledCard item in Model.CancelledCards) { %>
```

I've then tried to use

```
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(item >= item.Checked) %>
```

but I'm getting an error.

What am I missing? What's the right way to do this in MVC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# a lambda expression uses `=>` and not `>=`:

```
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(item => item.Checked) %>
```

Also instead of saying that you get an error, you could have posted the error message. It would have been much more clear.

Comment: D'oh! Should have spotted that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(item >= item.Checked) %>
```

is wrong.  It should be:

```
<%: Html.CheckBoxFor(item => item.Checked) %>
```