# Lambda notation and logical comparisons

Tags: c#, syntax

The lambda notation

```
x => x.MyProperty
```

is easily confused, by some humans, with greater than or equal to.  Ie

```
if (x => y) ...
```

the question is:  Does the compiler ever confuse these?  Ie, should one adopt a convention whereby greater than or equal to is always coded as:

```
if (x >= y) ...
```

I guess the compiler can distinguish between the two based on context, but what would be the "best practice"?

A question on SO

[ASP.NET MVC2 Checkboxes in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966823/asp-net-mvc2-checkboxes-in-a-table/3966852#3966852)

sort of showed that it is easy to get it wrong.

EDIT:

In light of the wee storm that has brewed up over this one, the following may clarify.

I asked the question because I answered a question where the guy had mistyped the lambda notation.  I pointed out his typo and he accepted my answer.  There is a link to the question above.

The question then niggled me.  I have always used >= for no very good reason, but was convinced that I had seen code that used the other notation.  Sometimes, you have assumptions that you don't think of questioning.  It may well be from my VBA days or not, but the conviction remains that I have seen code that compiles, runs and that uses => for the greater than comparison.  So be it.  My apologies for not "firing up VS", but I had been working all day with Sitefinity in an office with no VS installation.  No excuse, I grant you.

But note that lambda expressions in C# are only as old as...  .NET 2?  or was it .NET 3.5.  Given that I have used C# on and off since version 1.0, the question is wrong, but not that absurd.

I also think that the rigid rules of SO are great in that they produce pristine Q&A.  But there are different ways of applying the rules.  I have only been using SO in earnest since mid September, so I think it is best to fire a warning shot at bad questions rather than jerking the knee cap at the first opportunity.  That is what SO encourages:  to leave a comment rather than just trigger happy marking down.  You give the asker the chance to realise their mistake and delete a pointless question from the system.  Because once the answers and the votes flood in, the question cannot be deleted by the asker.

End of rant.

Comment: Interesting question, though in practice I've never seen anyone attempt to use => as a comparison operator. Furthermore, by way of conventions, every book I own on programming presents the logical GREATER THAN comparison operator as '>='

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question? Good grief... The OP has a reasonable point about human confusion. And being mistaken about what's valid C# syntax doesn't make the question bad IMO. It's an opportunity to learn.

Comment: @LarsH: Because the question makes no sense. => cannot be used for equality comparison, it wouldn't compile. Furthermore, suggesting that the compiler confuses the two, is a bit absurd IMO.

Comment: @BFree: the question makes perfect sense based on the OP's mistaken assumption that => and >= can both be used for comparison. As does the suggestion that the compiler needs context to distinguish the two. IMO, exposing a significant mistaken assumption and getting it corrected is almost as useful as asking a q (without mistaken assumptions) and getting it answered. No sense punishing people for asking honest, clear questions. "You don't know what you don't know" - until you ask.

Comment: @LarsH: Before asking a question like that, the very lease you could do is fire up Visual Studio, and test to make sure that what you're stating as fact, is in fact accurate.

Comment: @Brian, @LarsH, @BFree: LarsH is correct, and the question is not at all absurd. There are popular languages in which >= and => have the same semantics. VBScript immediately comes to mind. The VB IDE will automatically correct => to >= but if you override the autocorrect and force it to compile with => then compilation will still succeed.

Comment: @LarsH: In light of what Eric pointed out, I stand corrected. Removed my -1.

Comment: @Brian, @BFree: thank you. On further reflection I realize that the line between voting someone down because they are saying misleading and wrong about the subject they're commenting on (most appropriate for *answers* where someone claims to be knowledgeable), and voting someone down because they don't know their assumptions are wrong when asking a question, is somewhat subjective. But I think there is a worthwhile difference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`if (x => y)` is invalid code.

The comparison operators (`x >= y` and `x <= y`) must have the `<>` before the `=` sign.

Thus, it is not possible for the compiler (or a detail-oriented human) to confuse them.

Comment: It is perfectly valid *syntax*. The error occurs during semantic analysis, not syntactic or lexical analysis, because the lambda expression cannot be converted to bool.

Comment: I suspect my misconception comes from the fact that I started with MS Access.  I have tested this assumption with Access 2007 and it doesn't complain, it just auto realigns  the characters.  Ie, => becomes >=.  Not so sure about Access 200x.  I'm pretty sure I have seen VBA code in working apps that make no distinction.  Maybe I should have fired up VS to test...

Comment: Eric:  so was this error raised in the not so distant days before lambda expressions?

Answer (score 3):

=> is lambda operator

grater or equal is >=

I dont think that it can be confused, because they are not interchangeable

Answer (score 3):

> Does the compiler ever confuse these?

No. In C# (I'm looking at the tag) `>=` is always comparison; `=>` is always a lambda expression. There is [no `=>` comparison operator in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28VS.71%29.aspx).

> I guess the compiler can distinguish
>   between the two based on context

The compiler doesn't need context to distinguish the two; see above.

> Ie, should one adopt a convention
>   whereby greater than or equal to is
>   always coded as:
>
> if (x >= y) ...

Yes, because that is the only way the compiler will accept it. :-)

Regarding human error, I think the following mnemonics help:

- We almost always say "greater than or equal to" as opposed to "equal to or greater than".
- Math symbols put the "greater than" or "less than" above the line that symbolizes "or equals". This can translate into a left-to-right order pretty naturally.
- The symbol used for a lambda expression in C# looks like an arrow, pointing toward the expression for the returned value. It can be thought of as "yields".